# Create a Priority Queue sorted by values from a Hashmap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, priority-queue, comparator

I'm trying to add the keys in the hash map (it is a static variable of the class) playerToBook to a priority queue sorted by the values and I'm getting an error on line

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> maxBooksList = new PriorityQueue<>(playerToBook.size(), comparator);
```

saying PriorityQueue cannot be applied to the comparator.

```
public static PriorityQueue<Integer> playerWithMaxBooks() {

        Comparator<HashMap.Entry<Integer, Integer>> comparator = new fCompare();
        PriorityQueue<Integer> maxBooksList = new PriorityQueue<>(playerToBook.size(), comparator);
        Iterator it = playerToBook.entrySet().iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {

            HashMap.Entry pair = (HashMap.Entry) it.next();
            maxBooksList.add((Integer)pair.getKey());
        }

        return maxBooksList;
    }

    public static class fCompare implements Comparator<HashMap.Entry<Integer, Integer>>
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(HashMap.Entry<Integer, Integer> e1, HashMap.Entry<Integer, Integer> e2)
        {
            if (e1.getValue() < e2.getValue())
            {
                return -1;
            }
            if (e1.getValue() > e1.getValue())
            {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Please help!

Comment: If you want a PriorityQueue<Integer>, you need a Comparator<Integer>, not a Comparator<HashMap.Entry<Integer, Integer>>. Why don't you store the entries in your queue (or better, instances of a class with named attributes)

Comment: Please adhere to the Java naming conventions.

Comment: You should not use raw types in your code. `Iterator it` and `HashMap.Entry pair` should be declared with generics, and that would obviate the need for your boiler-plate casts. Also, it's `Map.Entry`.